# Does anyone say electric egg beater?

Tags: difference, usage, american-english

Picture of the device I am referring to:

[image: mixer]

Is it more common to call this device an electric mixer or an electric egg beater? As I understand it, an egg beater can be used for any kitchen utensil that beats ingredients such as eggs or cream, but I'm not sure if people use the word *electric* egg beater...

Comment: Back when I was a kid, we mostly used the hand-cranked egg beater to whip cream, but we still called it an egg beater. When electric ones came along, we called them electric egg beaters. I don't think anyone calls them that anymore. I would call it a hand mixer now.

Comment: Thank you @SarahT - very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard anyone refer to that device as an electric egg beater, but apparently some people do:

["Top 10 Best Electric Egg Beaters in 2020 Review"](https://toptenproductreview.com/best-electric-egg-beaters-review/)

If you look at this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=electric+hand+mixer%2Celectric+egg+beater&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celectric%20hand%20mixer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectric%20egg%20beater%3B%2Cc0), you'll see that "electric hand mixer" has been more popular than "electric egg beater" since the 1970s and that "electric egg beater" is becoming ever less common.

Both expressions are substantially less popular than "electric mixer," but that phrase also applies to stand mixers, so it's hard to compare.

Anecdotally, not only have I never heard anyone say "electric egg beater," I can't even remember the last time I heard anyone say "egg beater," since those devices (the ones that are hand-cranked) are not very popular these days.